# ImageMagick: resizing single image with multiple image sizes with their names on windows

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick

I am try to get the width and height of some 50 images as variable and then with that variable trying to resize one particular image making 50 copies with those dimensions.
Below code is only giving single image output. Kindly help.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion  
  %~d1
  CD "%~p1"
  MD small
 FOR %%a in (*.jpg) DO (
    identify -format "%%w" imageA.jpg > w.txt
    set /p w=<w.txt
    identify -format "%%h" imageA.jpg > h.txt
    set /p h=<h.txt)
   FOR %%a in (*.jpg) DO (
    convert imageA.jpg -resize %w%x%h%! small\%%a
  )
)
```

I did some work around to the code and I am able to get copies of images with names in the specified folder, but dimension are not applied. how to fix this?

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion  
  %~d1
  CD "%~p1"
  MD small

 FOR %%f in (*.jpg) DO (
  set filename=%%f
    identify -format "%%w" %%f > w.txt
    set /p w=<w.txt
    identify -format "%%h" %%f > h.txt
    set /p h=<h.txt)
   FOR %%f in (*.jpg) DO (
    set filename=%%f
    convert imageA.jpg -resize %w%x%h%! small\%%~nxf
  )
)
```

Comment: where the `%%w` and `%%h` came from?

Comment: from imagemagick tool(identify) , got w(width) and h(height) info @npocmaka

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. Can you please try and clarify it. How are you going to get the sizes of 50 images in one variable? Is it an array? Do you want 50 copies of each image? Or is there one particular image that you want 50 copies of? Why do you want 50 copies - if they are copies they will all be the same. I don't understand!

Comment: @MarkSetchell - sorry for the confusion. Let me elobrate, I have an img - ImageA.jpg and there are another set of about 50 images with different sizes. I want ImageA.jpg in 50 sizes derived from 50 images set.

Comment: You are using `%%f` to control an inner loop inside another loop also controlled by `%%f`. Not sure if that is good...

Comment: @MarkSetchell: any suggestion please. or the better approach to do this. I am beginner at batch.

Comment: 'FOR %%f in (*.jpg) DO (
     for /f %%i in ('identify -ping -format "%%w %%h" %%f') do set W=%%i & set H=%%j
    convert imageA.jpg -resize %w%x%h%! small\%%f
  )
)'
The following code is doing the job of creating 50 copies of imageA.jpg  but with first image dimensions alone out of 50.@MarkSetchell

Comment: You are still using `FOR %%f` twice. Try using `FOR %%g` the second time.